# Why does 'ModuleNotFoundError' happen in python console?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-module

I'm using Pycharm and trying to run a piece of code in Python console. But when I run code like:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as io
import pandas as pd
```

I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'".
I have checked that I did installed these module package in Pycharm:
[image]

and they perform normally in the main window:

[image]

then why they cannnot be imported to python console? Is the reason that python console uses different environment from the main window?

Comment: That's a virtual environment in your pycharm project.

Comment: @Voo Would you tell me how to solve the problem? To change the environment?

Comment: The problem is those libraries are installed in a venv (virtual enviorment) and the console you are launching is probably from the Python base installation. You would have to [Configure Python console settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/interactive-console.html#python-console-settings) to launch the console corresponding to the venv that has those libraries installed.

Answer (score -1):

Pycharm uses a virtual environment for the projects, and the packages are installed in it. If you use the console inside your Pycharm project, it should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

run command line as administrator

and run commands

pip install numpy
pip install scipy.io
pip install pandas

then restart your system

also make sure the modules and your project file, file location are on the same disk

Comment: neither running as admin (that'll actually be a problem if you actually use separate accounts as is generally recommended) not restarting is necessary there